# PMD Eclipse plugin --> Error is : Could not set property

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rad, pmd

I am in  a pickle . I installed  the PMD  plugin for eclipse. But when i try to check  the code with it  i get this error pop up :

```
      org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Could not set property: net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.persprops active_rulset. Value is too long.
```

Now what can i do to get myself rid of this error ?

Comment: I have searched the internet also for all possible clues but to no avail .